# Correction for classical measurement error given restricted auxiliary model

Tags: measurement-error

I am interested in estimating $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ of the true model
\begin{align}
y = \beta_1 z_1^* + \beta_2 z_2^* + u
\end{align}
I only observe noisy measures of $z^*$:
\begin{align}
z_1 &= z_1^* + \epsilon_1 \\
z_2 &= z_2^* + \epsilon_2,
\end{align}
where $\epsilon$ are mean-zero and independent of each other and $z^*$. We are, in other words, in the world of classical measurement error.

I also observe $x_1,x_2$ generated from the models
\begin{align}
x_1 &= z_1^* + b_{1,2} \, z_2^* + v_1 \label{eq:s} \\
x_2 &= b_{2,1} \, z_1^* + z_2^* + v_2, \\
\end{align}
where $v$ are **not** independent of $u$ (but independent of $\epsilon$). In other words, $x$ is not an instrument in the usual sense. However, I do know that **$b_{1,1}=1,b_{2,2}=1$** in these auxiliary models.

My question is whether I can use this structure to obtain unbiased estimators of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$?

Thank you very much!

P.S. My intuition is that the estimates $\hat{b}_{1,1},\hat{b}_{2,2}$ from regressing $x$ on $z$ can inform us on the attenuation bias caused by measurement error (given that we know $b_{1,1}=b_{2,2}=1$). We can then scale $z_1$ by $\hat{b}_{1,1}$ and $z_2$ by $\hat{b}_{2,2}$ and use these scaled variables as regressors in the model of $y$ to obtain unbiased estimators of $\beta$. This should work when $z^*_1,z^*_2$ are independent, but I am not sure about the general case.